# Burninate or synonym multiple Angular 2 tags

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, synonym-request

I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350130/error-using-http-json-angularjs-2) that is tagged with [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0)[angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2).

At the time of this writing

- [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) has 2.4k question and a tag wiki
- [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) has 207 question and a tag wiki
- [angularjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) has 49 questions and no tag wiki

What should be done with these duplicate tags? Should one or all of them be burninated or should one or all of them be a synonym of the much more prominent [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) tag?

Comment: Agreed... obviously the two smaller ones were just failed attempts to find the first one.

Comment: Agreed, my gut reaction is to burninate the other two tags, but I wanted to bring it to meta for the communities opinion.

Comment: [Additional question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342561/it-is-possible-pass-the-value-of-an-id-from-a-template-to-function-angulasjs2) tagged with the same three tags (also by the same user)

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer the smaller tags become a synonym of [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2).  This would help preserve any potential questions that are *only* tagged with the smaller tags.

Comment: If the smaller tags were removed then I would expect them to be retagged with the larger version. 256 questions are a lot to retag, but its a number that I feel is still small enough that I could handle running through individually over a few days to ensure retagging is successful.